# TFS 2010 - Can Only Install Build Service

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, windows-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server

I am trying to install TFS 2010 Beta 1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

When the installer runs runs I only have the option of installing the build server.  All the other configuration steps are missing.

I have followed the steps at http://blogs.msdn.com/dstfs/archive/2009/05/15/installing-tfs-2010-on-windows-server-2008-r2-rc.aspx for setting up TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Anyone have any other ideas why this is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that my machine is a Domain Controller.  I am trying to setup a demo machine with Lab Manager, TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2010.

Because Lab Manager needs System Center Virtual Machine Manager and System Center Virtual Machine Manager needs to be installed on a domain, it is not possible to have a stand alone single machine setup to demo Lab Manager (because you need a Domain Controller and you cannot install TFS 2010 on a Domain Controller).

I may try to install TFS on a Virtual Machine

Comment: There is a TFS Ranger project on at the moment with regards to Virtualizing TFS. You can read more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/03/18/vsts-rangers-projects-project-announcement-vsts-tfs-virtualized-deployment.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can install TFS 2010 on a domain controller (at least with RTM). You may check the other prerequisites inside the installation manual: www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f&displaylang=en

See this blog post for more details: blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/10/01/tfs-2010-for-sourcesafe-users.aspx

Regards,

Sven
http://www.tfsblog.de

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would be related to a missing prerequsite. The current list of items to have pre-installed are:

- WSS 3.0
- SQL Server 2008
- IIS7

The TFS installation is fairly straight forward. It has a 2 pass installation process:

**Step 1**
Install the files onto the local hard-drive, no options to set except for a full install or custom where you could select to just install the build servers. Once complete it will reboot the machine.

**Step 2**
The configuration wizard will launch and allow you to configure all the other services. If this is not working something was not selected in Step 1. Also note that TFS 2010 Beta 1 **DOES NOT** check for prerequisites until the Wizard is launched.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have tried all of this.